# What does the forceDelivery flag of Twilio API exactly do?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I can't seem to find documentation on this. If I pass [forceDelivery](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/46bf3f014c8d02b551e339abf690d5589c40b8e7/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageResource.cs#L143) when constructing a message, how will the API behave differently compared to not passing it?

The only documentation I see is

```
<param name="forceDelivery"> The force_delivery </param>
```

which is rather useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No kidding ... there is seriously *no* documentation on this. After a good bit of digging though, I found that [Raj Rajamani](https://www.cohesity.com/company/leadership/), when he was Director of Product Management at Marketo, committed [TwilioUtility.java](https://github.com/rajrajamani/Marketo/blob/cc511eb5dfa73d606d7f1ca51d263b36d0e39ca5/2waySMS/app/common/TwilioUtility.java) to his Marketo repository, in which there are these lines of code:

```
/* perform additional check on phone number to see if it can receive SMS */
params.put("ForceDelivery", "false");
```

This seems to be consistent with the few comments I've seen around the internet in which people indicate that setting `ForceDelivery` to `true` will tell Twilio to skip validation of the receiving phone number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The parameter is also old and deprecated now, which is why it isn't documented and we don't recommend you use it. Great sleuthing on finding more information though!